# NoSuchElementException: key not found: 'int' with Spark Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm getting the following error while using Cassandra 3.0.5 and Scala 2.10:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 'int'
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.fromDriverType(ColumnType.scala:81)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.ColumnDef$.apply(Schema.scala:117)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchPartitionKey$1.apply(Schema.scala:199)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchPartitionKey$1.apply(Schema.scala:198)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:153)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1(Schema.scala:246)
```

Here are my Spark dependencies:

```
<!--  Spark dependancies -->
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId> 
    <version>1.4.1</version> 
  </dependency> 

  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId> 
    <version>1.4.1</version> 
  </dependency>  

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<!--  Connectors -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my Java code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
          conf.setAppName("Java API demo");
          conf.setMaster("local");
          conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
          conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042");
          conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms", "40000");
          conf.set("spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms", "200000");

          conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "username");
          conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "password");

          SimpleSpark app = new SimpleSpark(conf);
          app.run();
```

I believe the versions I used were compatible; what is causing this error?

Comment: Please edit your question properly.

Comment: Restructured question and title. Is there anywhere in your code where you request an `int` key? The error message says one does not exist, so perhaps you have misconfigured something, or are requesting an `int` when you should be requesting some other type?

Comment: I have same issue. it is working on with spark 1.5.2 and Cassandra 2.1.13.  while i have updated Cassandra version to 3.4 it's started throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Please Update your com.datastax.spark connector driver to **1.5.0-RC1** instead of 1.5.0-M3. it is bug in 1.5.0-M3.

```
<groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.5.0-RC1</version>
```